# Imagen no cargada por Glide en el primer click

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

tengo el siguiente método en un adapter del WindowInfoMarker donde intento cargar una imagen en mi marcador cuando hago click usando la librería Glide.

```
override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
    // 1rst - Get tag
    val pointOfInterest = marker.tag as? PointOfInterest ?: return null

    // 2nd - Inflate view and set values

    window.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.marker_title).text = pointOfInterest.title

    val image = window.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.marker_image)
    Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(pointOfInterest.imageUrl)
        .addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable>{
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                Log.d("glide","Error loading the image url")
                return false
            }
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                Log.d("glide","Loaded")
                Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
                    if (marker.isInfoWindowShown) {
                        marker.showInfoWindow()
                    }
                }, 100)

                return false
            }

        })
        .into(image)

    return window
}
```

Este código lo copié de otro hilo que vi en stack overflow donde se hablaba del problema de carga de imágenes de Glide en ventanas de información de marcadores en Google Maps. El caso es que la primera vez que clico la imagen no se ha cargado, no me entra en ningún listener, mientras que a partir del segundo click en otra imagen ya se cargan todas (inclusive la primera).

Como podría solucionar este pequeño bug?

Comment: Podrías agregar la url del "hilo" que comentas por favor? Tienes una imagen de lo que sucede?

Comment: Ahora no recuerdo el hilo donde lo encontré. Voy a explicar que pasa exactamente cuando debugeo. La primera vez que hago click en un marcador, no pasa por el addListener del Glide y va directamente al into. Por eso no hace el Handler.postDelayed. En un segundo marcador ya pasa por ahi, de hecho pasa unas cuantas veces (debe ser por el Looper) y finalmente retorna la imagen en el .into

No sabria que imagen necesitas, primero se ve el cuadro de información del marcador sin imagen, y si hago click en otro marcador ya se ve con la imagen (sea siempre un marcador diferente). Luego se ve en todos